# Why is System.in not responding properly to synchronization attempts?

Tags: java, io, synchronization

I can't seem to force my calls to System.out to go in order if one of them takes input from a Scanner on System.in.

I'm sure that there's a simple answer (I can feel the down votes coming already), but it's eluding me.

```
public class RegexApp{
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
static String read = "";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {

           System.out.println("Please enter text."); 
           RegexApp.GetLine mg = new RegexApp().new GetLine();

           mg.start();
           mg.join();


    }
}
public class GetLine extends Thread{
    public void run()
    {

            read=s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(read);

    }
}
}
```

Even though I've tried using thread.join() to force the app to complete the System.out.println(read); before the next iteration of the while loop and printout of another System.out.println("Please enter text.");, I can't seem to get these two things to happen in the right order.
I'll often get another System.out.println("Please enter text.");, immediately followed by the result of  System.out.println(read); from the last line of input (vs. the reverse order as expected.)

It seems that the System.out call waiting for the input from System.in is just allowed to return whenever, and the app goes on with other System.out calls in the meantime.  I'd like to ensure that the app actually waits for the result of one System.out call before looping to the next.

(I have tried synchronized(System.out),(this) and (System.in), with wait() and notify(), all to no avail.)

---

I get

```
Please enter text.
(I type HELLO and hit enter)
Please enter text.
HELLO
(I type GOODBYE and hit enter)
Please enter text.
GOODBYE
```

where I'd have expected

```
Please enter text.
(I type HELLO and hit enter)
HELLO
Please enter text.
(I type GOODBYE and hit enter)
GOODBYE
Please enter text.
```

Basically, the order is inverted, and I can't figure out why.

---

I've seen a related question on the site in which the order of flushing of streams is mentioned, and the fix involving synchronized(System.out){} is given, but that did not solve this problem.

Comment: I think its just a case of delay in displaying the msg on the console... the actually processing might be happening correctly...

Comment: Works find for more.  You might consider adding `System.out.flush()` after the threaded output...

Comment: The flushing wasn't working (and, as mentioned, neither were synchronization attempts.)  I'd just about given up, having had the same problem across multiple applications whenever using these streams, but then I noticed that synchronization of System.in/System.out becomes less erratic when I directly run the same app from the console.  
I'm not absolutely certain of this, but I think that the problem may actually lie in my IDE (NetBeans.) 
Thanks to TheLostMind for pointing out this possibility.